# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I don't know whether it is an easy or a hard question, but for the proof of a stronger statement I need to know what the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}=\langle x,y\mid x^{-1}yx=y^{-1}\rangle$ are. (Indeed I only need to find the finitely generated subgroups, but I doubt there are non-finitely generated subgroups.)

At first sight I thought this was easy, since the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, but then I realized that the subgroups of a direct product are not the direct product of the subgroups. I read about Goursat's lemma, but this only work for direct products. My question is, the subgroups are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}\rtimes m\mathbb{Z}$? Or there are some other groups?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What homomorphism defines the semidirect product?

Comment: @Shaun: Since there are only two automorphisms, and one is trivial, unless this is a direct product it has to be inversion.

Comment: @Shaun I edited it, but I think that in this case there is only one semidirect product.

Comment: I see now. I'm sorry. Thank you, @ArturoMagidin.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5171/742

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that is a nice characterization, thanks! However, are there any easy way to prove it in this case? This is a fairly simple group and I want to avoid using such an strong theorem.

Comment: The group $\Bbb Z\rtimes \Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. So the question is the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34298/how-to-calculate-all-the-subgroups-of-the-fundamental-group-of-the-klein-bottle). The answer is: "The group is either trivial, free of rank one, free Abelian of rank two, or non-Abelian of rank two." See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/subgroups-klein-bottle?rq=1).